# m4 - executing a shell command

Tags: shell, autoconf, m4

I'm new to m4 and am trying to set up a macro which allows the user to specify the location of a library at configure-time `./configure --with-mylib=/path/to/lib.so`.

In the m4 macro using `AC_ARG_WITH`, I'll check that the given file actually exists, and then store the path to said lib. `MYLIB_PATH=esyscmd([dirname $withval])`. This produces the error:

```
dirname: missing operand
```

The shell doesn't seem to know about `$withval`. How do I get it through to execute this command?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Why not just let the user specify the location of the library by setting LDFLAGS?

Comment: As an environment variable before the build?

Comment: As an argument to configure, or in a config.site.  "./configure LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib" should work.

Comment: Is there any risk of that overriding stuff that needs to be there?

Comment: LDFLAGS is intended to be set only by the user.  There is a chance that the package maintainer has incorrectly modified LDFLAGS or done something else unusual, but LDFLAGS is a user variable and the user is allowed to set it.  If doing so breaks the build, it is a packaging bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `esyscmd` is executed by `m4` when generating your `configure` script, i.e. at "compile time". Use

```
MYLIB_PATH=`dirname $with_mylib`
```

instead.

Note that `$withval` "is actually just the value of the shell variable named `with_package`, with any non-alphanumeric characters in package changed into `_`", so all occurrences of `/` will be removed and it will likely not be a valid path.

Comment: Heh... that's the intuitive way that I for some reason thought I tried already. Thanks very much!